# How to Import Blender 3D Models into Webots

Tags: animation, scripting, export, blend-files

I am having trouble importing a Blender 3D Model into Webots. Currently, I am using Blender 2.79 and the most updated version of Webots. I am attempting to import the default cube model, but I am encountering an error when importing into Webots.[image]

What should I do??

Comment: Helo, without knowing the specifics of the other application it is very hard to know what went wrong. You are importing directly a .blend file ?

Comment: @Gorgious I am importing a .blend file directly into Webots by using the Import 3D Model Button in the File Tab of Webots.

Comment: Then you might have to get intouch with the people of Webots, not very much we can do on the blender side... Are you sure the blend file actually contains the cube ? Maybe try to delete the camera and light if there is one...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a problem importing any 3D file, the texture does not import. I found a Webots importer for blender but it is not compatible with later versions of blender https://github.com/cyberbotics/blender-webots-exporter
If you've found another solution please share?